# Заменить 1011 в слове на 1101

Tags: ассемблер

Дано задание: заменить в заданном слове комбинации 1011 на комбинации 1101.

Не до конца понимаю, как делать это задание:

1. Копирую данные в регистр
2. Выделяю младшие 4 бита через AND с маской 1111
3. Делаю CMP c 1011.
4. В зависимости от результата я
       делаю JMP
5. Записываю результат в другой регистр(Пытаюсь собрать
       результат в другом регистре)
6. Восстанавливаю исходные данные в регистре(До применения AND) и делаю сдвиг на 1
7. Выполняю опять все проверки
8. Теперь нужно результаты этой итерации совместить с 5 шагом...
   Вот на этом шаге я не понимаю что делать... Как мне
       результаты текущей итерации объединить с результатами предыдущей
       итерации в результирующем регистре?

Буду признателен, если расскажете, как это делать или еще лучше кините пример на TASM.

Comment: Хм. А что должно получиться из слова `10111111b`? В зависимости от того, выполняете вы проверки слева направо или справа налево, будут разные результаты.

Comment: Мне сказали сравнивать справа налево.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

1. Текущая маска = 1111b, текущее число из данных в регистр, текущий сдвиг 0
2. Цикл:
3. Выделить дополнение маски (`not`) в другой регистр
4. Применить маску к числу (`and`) и сдвинуть вправо на значение текущего сдвига
5. Проверить результат, сравнить с `1011b`
6. Если не равно, переходим к пункту 8
7. Заменяем. Для этого вычисляем часть числа вне маски (`and` с дополнением маски), новую часть «под» маской (`1101b` сдвинутое влево на значение текущего сдвига) и соединяем их (`or`)
8. Сдвигаем маску влево на 1 бит, увеличиваем на 1 текущий сдвиг
9. Если текущий сдвиг всё ещё меньше разрядности данных, возвращаемся в пункт 2

Расписывать на ассемблере не буду, всё-таки учебное задание.

Ключевая идея: разделять данные на часть под маской и остальное.

Возможная оптимизация: цикл можно крутить лишь до тех пор, пока текущий сдвиг + 3 меньше разрядности данных. Выигрыш 3 итерации.

Comment: А в 4 шаге мы случайно не теряем старшие разряды, применяя and?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну, результат операции из шага 4 мы кладём в другой регистр, не затирая текущее число. Надеюсь, регистров хватит.

Comment: Я вот такой код смог написать, но почему-то он не работает корректно: Залил код сюда: http://rghost.ru/8yhjMWhSQ  так как если его вставить в комментарий, то теряется форматирование=(

Comment: @iluxa1810: Не нашёл в вашем коде дополнение маски. Вы делали как в ответе, или как в вопросе? Если как в вопросе, то это неправильно. PS: код лучше выкладывать на pastebin.com.